# CSS Font issue on iOS Phone

Tags: html, css, ios

There is a problem with fonts on **iOS devices**, these are the differences:

[ANDROID/WEB IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SXT3.jpg) (correct)

[IOS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY1l7.jpg) (wrong)

The text appears to be in **italics** but I have **never** set it.
This is my font-face:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Acumin Variable Concept";
    src: url("font/Acumin/Acumin-Variable-Concept.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Acumin Variable Concept";
    src: url("font/Acumin/Acumin-Variable-Concept.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Acumin Variable Concept";
    src: url("font/Acumin/Acumin-Variable-Concept.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Acumin Variable Concept";
    src: url("font/Acumin/Acumin-Variable-Concept.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-display: swap;
}

/* Typography */

p{
    font-family:'Acumin Variable Concept';
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

b{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--brand);
}
```

What could it be?

Thanks in advance,
Simone

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set behind your font an "!important" like

```
font-family: "Acumin Variable Concept" !important;
```

regards

Jonas